# Cannot use Stripe with nuxt and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, stripe-payments, nuxt.js

I've got a problem, I'm trying to implement Stripe on my nuxt/typescript projet, I use vue-property-decorator as well.

Here's my head in nuxt.config.js

```
head: {
        title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
        meta: [
            {charset: 'utf-8'},
            {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
            {hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''}
        ],
        script: [{
            src: "https://js.stripe.com/v3/",
            type: "text/javascript"}],
        link: [
            {rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'}
        ]
    },
```

My component:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Prop, Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";
    import {Subscription} from "~/models/Subscription";

    @Component({
        components: {}
    })
    export default class PaymentForm extends Vue {

        @Prop()
        public subscription: Subscription;

        mounted() {
            let stripe = Stripe(`MY PUBLIC KEY`),
            elements = stripe.elements(),
            card = undefined;
            card = elements.create("card");
            card.mount(this.$refs.card);
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I got this error

```
Cannot find name 'Stripe'. Did you mean 'stripe'?
```

So I can't build my project, can you help me? I tried to just write this component in js and it worked but I'd like to keep my ts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe property is accessible on client side as `window.Stripe` after sdk script is loaded. During development TypeScript has no reference for global variable `Stripe`.

One way to fix it, is to create definitions for `Stripe` property on global `window` object.

This can be done by creating (or extending if exists) type definitions of `Window` class. In type definitions folder create a file `global.d.ts` (or any other) with following code:

```
interface Window {
  Stripe: any;
}
```

This will extend default `Window` class and allow to use Stripe without errors in your code like this:

```
const stripe = window.Stripe('MY PUBLIC KEY')
```

Note that this will not provide completion for sdk methods and properties.

Comment: Oh thank you, but where can I found the "type definitions folder" in my nuxt project? :)

Comment: If you do not have it yet, create a folder `types` on the same level as `tsconfig.json`. For Nuxt.js projects it is usually project root with all the `pages`, `plugins`, etc. TypeScript resolves `*.d.ts` files, but single folder will help to keep global definitions in one place.